# How to clear 'filterBy' filters?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

I've created a simple user table with a column containing each user's country. Below the table there are two buttons: the first one is supposed to filter table rows and hide users from countries outside of the European Union; the second is supposed to reset (clear) the filtering and show all rows again.

While I've managed to get the first button working perfectly (using **Bootstrap-table's** `filterBy` method), I have no idea how to implement the second one. I've tried applying empty filter or calling `reset` and `getHiddenRows(true)`, but filtered rows are still hidden. There are no JS errors in the console.

PS. I am using the newest stable versions of Bootstrap, Bootstrap-table and jQuery.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Test</title>

        <link href="vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="vendor/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="mainTable" data-toggle="table" data-classes="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" data-field="USER_ID">User ID</th>
                        <th scope="col" data-field="FIRST_NAME">First name</th>
                        <th scope="col" data-field="LAST_NAME">Last name</th>
                        <th scope="col" data-field="EMAIL">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col" data-field="COUNTRY">Country</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>John</td><td>Smith</td><td>john.smith@example.com</td><td>US</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>2</td><td>Jane</td><td>Doe</td><td>jane.doe@example.com</td><td>ES</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>3</td><td>Alice</td><td>Something</td><td>alice@example.com</td><td>FR</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>4</td><td>Bob</td><td>Jones</td><td>bjonesss@example.com</td><td>UK</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <footer>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnFilterEU">EU countries only</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btnClearFilter">Clear filter</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <!-- JavaScript -->

        <script src="vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#btnFilterEU').click(function() {
                    $('#mainTable').bootstrapTable('filterBy', {}, {
                        'filterAlgorithm': (row, filters) => { return ['DE', 'FR', 'ES', 'BE' /* ... */].includes(row.COUNTRY); }
                    });
                });

                $('#btnClearFilter').click(function() {
                    // doesn't do anything :(
                    $('#mainTable').bootstrapTable('filterBy', {});
                    $('#mainTable').bootstrapTable('getHiddenRows', true);
                    $('#mainTable').bootstrapTable('refresh');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution: my custom filtering algorithm simply passes all rows through when its argument `filters` is an empty object `{}`.

```
$(function() {
    $('#mainTable').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
        filterOptions: {
            filterAlgorithm: (row, filters) => {
                return jQuery.isEmptyObject(filters) || ['DE', 'FR', 'ES', 'BE' /* ... */].includes(row.COUNTRY);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#btnFilterEU').click(function() {
        $('#mainTable').bootstrapTable('filterBy', {'foo' : 'bar'});  // the values do not matter
    });

    $('#btnClearFilter').click(function() {
        $('#mainTable').bootstrapTable('filterBy', {});
    });
});
```